# react native android how to increase dbMaximumSize?

Tags: android, react-native

I know about this:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/storage/ReactDatabaseSupplier.java#L144

But I am not sure how or where to use this method in an actual project. Please Help

Comment: Can you check which code is calling that method and with what arguments? Is it possible to call that code from JavaScript?

Comment: I don't think so, the `setMaximumSize` method is called by method 1, which is further used in react-native via method 2 in several places. Because of private encapsulation, these methods are hard to extend.

1. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/storage/ReactDatabaseSupplier.java#L78

2. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/storage/AsyncStorageModule.java#L387